# Securely use Blockly generated code

Tags: python, django, blockly

I'm using Google Blockly plugin in order to build some logical blocks, rules, etc...

Blockly can generate python code directly from the blocks positioned into the canvas: [DEMO](https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/demos/code/index.html)

Now, I've integrated Blockly to my django web application, and I'm wondering if this is a good approach, that permits me to use the generated python code SAFELY into my web application, preventing malicious code injection directly to my webserver.

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: There's no way to run arbitrary code absolutely safely. But there are all kinds of techniques to reduce the exposure. Instead of directly `exec`ing it in your process, you can run it as a child process. You can put that child process in a chroot jail, and run it as a limited user. You can even run it in an isolated container/virtual machine that has no connection with your real machine except stdin/stdout pipes. Or you can build an interpreter (or modify an existing one like CPython) that doesn't allow anything dangerous. And so on.

Comment: Of course the more complicated you get, the more likely you are to make an exploitable mistake. And, in general, how much work you want to do to protect your Django server depends on how important that server is to protect.

Comment: Thanks, basically i need to inject these generated snippet to a thread that runs every minute, with the code defined in the blocks, i'll check the defined rules and then send mails, do an http request, and so on...
In any case, i need to access the database...